# Help using iOSPorts to connect to an LDAP server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ldap

I am building an iPhone application which connects to an LDAP server (no encryption). I am trying to use iOSPorts but I am having trouble following the [documentation](https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts), I think it was written for Xcode 3, while I've only ever used Xcode 4.

All that is required is to do simple search queries of the server and returning the results.

Some of the trouble I am having:

For example in step 3 my iOSPorts/include folder is empty and only contains the .gitignore file.

For step 4 which files do I need to add just the ports folder containing database, devel, iOSPorts and security?

For step 6 the direct dependencies panel, is this the target dependencies of build phases , which libraries need to be selected?

I think step 7 is for Xcode 3 too,

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried emailing the project maintainer for iOSPorts? syzdek@bindlebinaries.com

Comment: Have you resolved your issues?  I recently built the project in xcode 4.3.2 on OS X Lion and had to use one of their branches on github.

Answer (score 1):

> I am building an iPhone application which connects to an LDAP server (no encryption). I am trying to use iOSPorts but I am having trouble following the documentation, I think it was written for Xcode 3, while I've only ever used Xcode 4.

The original instructions were created for Xcode 3 since Xcode 4 was still in early beta when I published the first release of iOS Ports.  The instructions have been updated within the last month for use with Xcode 4.  I try to use the name used by "Xcode 4 User Guide" when describing the steps, so I recommend reading the first few chapters of this document from Apple.

> For example in step 3 my iOSPorts/include folder is empty and only contains the .gitignore file.

Initially the include directory will be empty. The individual ports will copy the header files to the include directory.  This is to prevent the end developer from needing to add a path to OpenSSL, Cyrus SASL, and OpenLDAP in order to compile an app for OpenLDAP.

> Any help with this would be much appreciated!

So here is a quick run down of how iOS Ports works.

Each port of an Open Source package has an Xcode project file.  That Xcode project file lists other Xcode project files and Makefiles as dependencies. Here is the high level steps used by an iOS Ports Xcode project file to compile the port:

- Execute the port's MakeFile

  - Makefile: Download the source archive from the Internet (fails if Internet is unavailable)
  - Makefile: Verifies the integrity of the source archive using md5sum.
  - Makefile: Unpacks the source archive.
  - Makefile: Applies any required patches to the source code.
  - Makefile: Copies headers to the iOS Ports include directory.
- Build any libraries from other ports listed in the build settings' Target Dependencies (for instance, libldap.a in OpenLDAP requires libsasl2.a from Cyrus SASL).
- Compiles requested library.

The README has more information on how to add the project files to your project and link against the libraries.  There also a few example programs in the examples directory.

If you do continue to have problems, please let me know.  I try my best to keep on top of requests for help regarding iOS Ports and my other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through all the process, but I am pretty sure for step 3, you have to 'make' the project first. There is a Makefile in the top folder of the project.